# How to get second or third substring from string after split?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm trying to get 2nd or 3rd substring from string after string.Split().
This is my code:

```
string[] rows;
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    rows = File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName);

    foreach (var row in rows)
    {
        row.Split('\n');
        if (!row.StartsWith("#COLUMN"))
        {           
            if (row.Contains("Data") || row.Contains("Godzina"))
            {
                var wiersz = row.Split(';')[1] + row.Split(';')[2];
                richTextBox1.Text += wiersz;
            }                
        }
    }                
}
```

`wiersz` contains nothing after that.

This is row I'm trying to Split and get substrings from:

`27590;2012-12-07;14:44:20;1;[001]: Przyznanie dostępu;136;2711;XXX;;;;XXX XXX;410;PORTIERNIA WEJŚCIE;0;Domyślna;16;UMYSŁOWY;0;WEJŚCIE;4400F2E180;292073693568;`

Comment: What is the problem? Please explain what you mean by *`wiersz` contains nothing after that*. If you want to access this variable later, declare it earlier.

Comment: remove the line `row.Split('\n');`. it doesnt make sense at all

Comment: Your sample string does not contain "Data" or "Godzina", so that "var wiersz" part is skipped (for that line).

Comment: Delete `if (row.Contains("Data") || row.Contains("Godzina"))`, or find other "anchor" strings. Else, use [a regex like this](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cs*%5cd%2b%3b(%3f%3cdata%3e%5cd%7b4%7d-%5cd%7b2%7d-%5cd%7b2%7d)%3b(%3f%3cczas%3e%5cd%7b2%7d%3a%5cd%7b2%7d%3a%5cd%7b2%7d)%3b&i=27590%3b2012-12-07%3b14%3a44%3a20%3b1%3b%5b001%5d%3a+Przyznanie+dost%c4%99pu%3b136%3b2711%3bXXX%3b%3b%3b%3bXXX+XXX%3b410%3bPORTIERNIA+WEJ%c5%9aCIE%3b0%3bDomy%c5%9blna%3b16%3bUMYS%c5%81OWY%3b0%3bWEJ%c5%9aCIE%3b4400F2E180%3b292073693568%3b). Does it answer  your question?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should probably remove this line, as it doesn't make sense:

```
 row.Split('\n');
```

Then split your split code into two parts:

> var wiersz = row.Split(';')[1] + row.Split(';')[2];

becomes

```
var splitString = row.Split(';');
if (splitString == null || splitString.Length == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Split string is null or empty!");
}
else
{
    var wiersz = splitString[1] + splitString[2];
}
```

This way `Split()` only runs once and you should get the proper results. A troubleshooting thing you could do is iterate over the `splitString` array and output the results:

```
foreach (string s in splitString)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

You could also put breakpoints in your code to make sure it even reaches your split string code - are all your checks along the way properly setup?

Comment: It occurs error: index was outside the bounds of the array

Comment: See my edited answer and check your console for error logs. You could also try printing the contents of `row`: `Console.WriteLine(row);` to get a better understanding of what you're looking at and should be checking for.